# how to display url in text without site name, without slash, merged?

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to display url in text without site name, without slash, merged?

Example site url: sitename.site/job/cvs/index.html

How do I get the text: "jobcvs"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you want to be able to get the joined path of any URL. If this is the case you can use the [URL api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) to get the pathname, split it on "/" and join everything except the file name back together and return the result. Below is what I've come up with. This could probably be reduced to a one-liner, but I've left it long form for readability.

```js
function getJoinedPathname(url) {
  const urlObj = new URL(url);
  const pathnameSplit = urlObj.pathname.split('/')

  return pathnameSplit.reduce((a, b, index) => {
    if (index !== pathnameSplit.length - 1)  return a + b;
    return a
  })
}

console.log(getJoinedPathname('https://sitename.site/job/cvs/index.html'))
console.log(getJoinedPathname('https://sitename.site/job/cvs/anotherpath/index.html'))
console.log(getJoinedPathname('https://sitename.site/job/cvs/1/2/3/index.html'))
console.log(getJoinedPathname('https://sitename.site/job/cvs/index.html?name=test'))
console.log(getJoinedPathname('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64055299/how-to-display-url-in-text-without-site-name-without-slash-merged'))
console.log(getJoinedPathname(window.location.href))
```

Comment: can you do an example from the current page?

Comment: I've added the example as requested. Note that you can use window.location.href to get the current url, but because of the way the code is executed it will not have a path to join and return blank.

Comment: I'm not sure i understand. What does not work about it?

Comment: console.log(getJoinedPathname(window.location.href))

Comment: It does work, but the code snippet runs in an iframe which has a different URL (https://stacksnippets.net/js). This URL has no path to join as it's only one level deep.

Comment: but how to do it for any level?

Comment: That is doing it for any level. It's just that there's no levels there to join, so it returns blank.

Comment: then the network if you use this code on your site, it will not be empty?

Comment: It will only return an empty string if the pathname is one level deep. So if the URL is 'example.com/index.html' it will return blank, but 'example.com/level1/index' will return `level1` and 'example.com/level1/level2/index' will return `level1level2`.

Comment: listen. is it realistic to find a job on a front-end? I don't have enough money. Can you help with work?

Comment: I have a great knowledge of the engineering part. Strong in css. jq / js is gaining ground.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222050/discussion-between-cody-pace-and-vladimir-rodichev).

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
const url = "sitename.site/job/cvs/index.html"
const parts = url.split("/");
parts.shift();
parts.pop();
const res = parts.join('');
```